# EmguCV setting specific value to Mat C#

Tags: c#, emgucv, mat

I'm creating deep neural network with EmguCV in C#, and to train said neural network, I need to put labels into `Mat` format. I´ve created my Mat like this:

`Mat responses = Mat.Zeros(trainData.Rows, distinctLabelCount.Count, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 1);`

It creates `Mat` of zeros of size (400,10) as type `float` and with grayscale values if I understood correctly.

Now I have 400 rows of input data and 10 labels and I need to replace `0` value at certain positions to encode correct label into the mat. like at position (0,1) for value of 1 ,,, position (3,5) to set label 5 for 4th row etc.

All I've seen so far from googling was method `responses.at<float>(...);`, but that was probably in C++ and I cannot seem to access that method in C#. So I'm stuck not knowing how to edit values in Mat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to c++ opencv at() in C# is the index operator:

pixel = image[x, y]

image[x, y] = pixel;

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value at row `r` and column `c` to `newvalue` using `Marshal.Copy` like this:

```
float newvalue = 1;
float [] mv = new float [] { newvalue };
Marshal.Copy(mva, 0, responses.DataPointer + (r * responses.Cols + c) * responses.ElementSize, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting individual values on a Mat is a bit tricky.

- You can either use the Matrix<DepthType.Cv32F> class instead Mat.

  ```
   var matrix = new Matrix<DepthType.Cv32F>(rows, cols);
   matrix[0, 0] = 3;
  ```
- Or setting the values of a flaot[,] array that underlays a Mat object.

  ```
   var imagedata = new float[rows, cols];
   GCHandle imageDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(imagedata, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var m = new Mat(rows, cols, DepthType.Cv32F, imageDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
   imagedata[0, 0] = 3;
   imageDataHandle.Free();
  ```